# Problems with inserting emojis into database using mysql.connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, character-encoding, utf8mb4

As described in the title, I have a problem with inserting emojis into a MariaDB database using the `mysql.connector` module in python.

When I try to insert the data containing emojis into the database with python, all emojis are simply replaced by question marks. I have also made sure that the emojis work in python by outputting them to the console before inserting them into the database.

Inserting the emojis via phpMyAdmin is no longer a problem after I changed the collation in the database to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. So I could make sure that there is no problem with the database.

If it helps in any way the data I'm inserting comes from the steam API and consists of nicknames.

I would now like to know if anyone knows how I can fix this problem.

I hope I have not forgotten any important information.

Comment: Nice job with your first question! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that emoji are representable in Unicode. Did you remember to set the [connection character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-set-charset-collation.html) and collation in your Python program?

Something like this might help right as you [open the connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html).

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='JonaWe', database='test',
                              use_unicode=True,
                              charset='utf8mb4,
                              collation='utf8mb4_general_ci',
                              etcetera)
cnx.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_general_ci')
```

The connection between Python and MySQL might be garbling the utf8mb4 contents of your emoji.

Comment: I didn't know I had to change the charset collation in pyhton too. I tried it and using `'utf8mb4'` and `'utf8mb4_general_ci'` as a parameter resulted in the following error: `unknown encoding: utf8mb4`. Then I tried to remove the first parameter, but without that it crashed imidiatly.

Comment: Inserting works now, but as soon as I am trying to select some date I get the unknown encoding: utf8mb4 error.

Comment: It seems possible you have a version of MySQL that predates the availability of `utf8mb4`.  Upgrade?

Comment: You are right. My problem back them was that I installed the wrong version of the package. I installed `pip install mysql.connector` instead of `pip install mysql-connector-python`. After switching to the correct version, I had no more problems. @O.Jones